# DOS emulator for Android devices

Tags: android, emulator, dos

I'm looking for a DOS emulator for Android devices that enables us to run the DOS operating system.

Paid or Free

which supports

- configuring the controls,
- playing DOS video games
- with enriched advance features

Comment: Not sure which one fits the bill (not using one myself) – but while waiting for answers, be welcome to check with my tiny list of [DOS-Emus](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators#group_186) for Android. If you find there what you're looking for, please [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then :) Good luck!